# Title plus caption beneath figure

Tags: floats, captions

I would like my figures to have a title and beneath that a longer caption in a smaller font. Please see the image for an example of the desired format. The title, however, does not need to be in bold as in the image. The longer caption should also be left aligned. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: desired caption format]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `caption` and define your own command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\captionsetup{
  singlelinecheck=false,
  labelsep=newline,
  labelfont=bf,
  justification=raggedright,
}

\newcommand{\captiondesc}[2]{\caption[#1]{\textbf{#1}\\#2}}


\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image}

\captiondesc{Aggregate SKRISK by industry}{The figure shows the plot of
aggregate SKRISK between January~2005 and December~2012. Aggregate
SKRISK is layered by financial industry group. The industry groups are
(from top to bottom) Others, Insurance, Depositories, and Broker-Dealers.
The solid vertical line marks the Lehmans Brothers bankruptcy.}

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

With `justification=justified`, instead:

[image]

With smaller font size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\captionsetup{
  singlelinecheck=false,
  labelsep=newline,
  labelfont=bf,
  justification=justified,
}

\newcommand{\captiondesc}[2]{%
  \caption[#1]{%
    \textbf{#1}\par\smallskip
    \footnotesize#2%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image}

\captiondesc{Aggregate SKRISK by industry}{The figure shows the plot of
aggregate SKRISK between January~2005 and December~2012. Aggregate
SKRISK is layered by financial industry group. The industry groups are
(from top to bottom) Others, Insurance, Depositories, and Broker-Dealers.
The solid vertical line marks the Lehmans Brothers bankruptcy.}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]